# Xcode simulator showing white png

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an xib file shows a png image fine in Xcode 9 but when previewed in the iPhone 5S simulator renders as a white image.

[image: XCode simulator on the left and xib on the right]

The app is working absolutely fine otherwise. This is the screen that pops up as an overlay with a book purchase offer. The buy now link button png shows up fine, but the background png (splashbg_US_568h.png) is white.

I've tried removing the images from the index and adding them again and different simulator hardware, but with the same result.

Here's my xib code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="9531" systemVersion="14F27" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none">
<dependencies>
<deployment identifier="iOS"/>
<plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="9529"/>
</dependencies>
<objects>
<placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="SplashScreenViewController">
<connections>
<outlet property="mAmazonButton" destination="7" id="Vsp-QR-ycJ"/>
<outlet property="mBgImageView" destination="4" id="16"/>
<outlet property="view" destination="1" id="3"/>
</connections>
</placeholder>
<placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="1">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
<subviews>
<imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" image="splashbg_US_568h.png" id="4">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
<gestureRecognizers/>
</imageView>
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="7">
<rect key="frame" x="98" y="475" width="125" height="38"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="15"/>
<state key="normal" image="splash.com.png">
<color key="titleColor" red="0.19607843459999999" green="0.30980393290000002" blue="0.52156865600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
<color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
</state>
<state key="highlighted">
<color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
</state>
<connections>
<action selector="buyAmazon:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="xYa-Ye-bxK"/>
</connections>
</button>
</subviews>
<color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
<gestureRecognizers/>
<nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
</view>
</objects>
<resources>
<image name="splash.com.png" width="125" height="44"/>
<image name="splashbg_US_568h.png" width="115.21728515625" height="172.825927734375"/>
</resources>
</document>
```

One final thing I should mention is that although I designed the app and paid for it, but I didn't code it so I've pretty limited understanding of an Xcode project. I've just updated the images and plist and am preparing to issue a new update.

Edit: Checked that the image is in Copy Bundle Resources and it is:
[image: splashbg_US_568h.png in Copy Bundle Resources]

TIA

Comment: Make sure splashbg_US_568h.png is added to Xcode 'Copy Bundle Resources'

Comment: Found Copy Bundle Resources (thanks google) and it's there. See screenshot in edited post above.

Comment: Use the view debugger to look at the image view at runtime and check it is positioned in the view and view hierarchy correctly.

Comment: fixed it. I had changed a hyphen to an underscore when updating images. In doing so, I broke `sizeSuffix = @"-568h"` in the ViewController file. I never did find the view debugger, but simply played around until I located a file that seemed to have something to do with the images for that view.